# User to add/remove products to product bundle

Tags: commerce

I want to create a product bundle of say 10 products, but with the ability for the user to add or remove further items to the bundle.
Essentially I have a bundle of products I offer at a discount, and I want the user to retain the discount if they remove an item or add another (or both).
Hope that makes sense.
If anyone has any idea of a way to achieve this, or a way to potentially achieve it, i'd appreciate the tips.
Thanks